# iOS Basic Auth completion error first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsurlconnection, basic-authentication

I have implemented this piece of code for basic auth and sometimes doesn't work on first time:

```
func doRequestWithBasicAuth(completion : (success : Bool, html: String?, error : NSError?) -> Void) {
    if let user = self.user {
        let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", user.login!, user.pwd!)
        let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
        let url = NSURL(string: user.service!.getURL())
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let htmlString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                completion(success: true, html: htmlString as? String, error: nil)
            } else {
                completion(success: false, html: nil, error: error)
            }
        }
    } else {
        completion(success: false, html: nil, error: NSError())
    }
}
```

This method is attached to a button, so on first tap I get this error:

> BASIC AUTH ERROR: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7bad5770
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https:///auth/Logon.do,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https:///auth/Logon.do,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7b9c47f0 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}

On second tap, call works fine... I can't understand why.. I print user login, psw and url: are the same on twice calls..

Any idea?